# Evaluation of a rational function vs formal power series

Tags: rational-functions, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a complete valued field and $X$ be an indeterminate $K[X]$ be the ring of polynomials over $K$ in the indeterminate $X$ and $K(X)$ be its quotient field.
For $a\in K$, consider the evaluation map $\sigma_a:K(X) \to K$ defined by $\sigma_a(P/Q)=P(a)/Q(a)$ when $Q(a)\ne 0$.
Now consider $K(X)$ embeded in $K((X))$. Suppose that $R(X)\in K(X)$, $R(X)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nX^n$. Consider its evaluation now by $R(a)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_na^n$ if $a$ is in the disk of convergence of the power series. I wonder why both evaluation gives the same result. I thought it would be easy to prove but I did not manage to do it

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What "disk of convergence" are you thinking about?  There is no distance function on $K$.

Comment: What do you mean by $R(X)\in K(X)$?

Comment: I think you are using $R(X)$ for two different things

Comment: I edited my post. please have a look.

Comment: $P(X)/Q(X) = \sum a_n X^n$ means $P(X) = Q(X)\sum a_n X^n$ where this RHS uses multiplication of power series.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see what you means. Once I did the multiplcation of $Q(X)\sum a_nX^n$ and evaluate I do not know how to recover $Q(a)$.